# Postgres One to Many join type

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, many-to-many, one-to-many

The picture I'm attaching hopefully says it all. I tried INNER JOIN and then every other join type I know. I google searched. I'm also not sure if you call this one-to-many or many-to-many.
[image]

Finally, two items:
(1) The t_part_no and t_part_no_parent fields are both indexed but no foreign keys. If the SQL is written correct, I shouldn't *need* foreign keys, right?
(2) Maybe I'm putting my WHERE clause in the wrong spot. This is the where:
tbl_items_to_items.t_part_no_no_parent='p_crusher_01'.

I've also tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_items 
WHERE t_part_no IN (
SELECT t_part_no_parent as t_part_no 
FROM tbl_items_to_items
WHERE t_part_no_parent like 'p-crusher-01' );
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! This worked:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_items 
WHERE t_part_no IN (
SELECT t_part_no 
FROM tbl_items_to_items
WHERE tbl_items_to_items.t_part_no_parent like 'p-crusher-01' );
```